click on i class value (C# Selenium)
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="$.post('dinamik/sorularList.php', {'page' : 5}, function(data){ 
                       $('#dataContainer').html(data); }); return false;"><i class="bi bi-arrow-right-square-fill"></i></a>

<i class="bi bi-arrow-right-square-fill"></i>

That's how I have value. Here I need to click on "bi bi-arrow-right-square-fill". More precisely, I need to click on this value. When I get the xpath, I can't click it.
I finally tried this
IWebElement elementa = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector(".<bi bi-arrow-right-square-fill>"));
IJavaScriptExecutor executor1 = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
executor1.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].click()", elementa);


What does it mean to click on the class attribute of an HTML element?

You need to add your XPath that didn't work and what the resulting error message was for both the XPath and CSS selector. Edit all that into your question as text, properly formatted.

Your CSS selector,
.<bi bi-arrow-right-square-fill>

is not valid syntax.
It should be
i.bi.bi-arrow-right-square-fill

or maybe more specifically,
a > i.bi.bi-arrow-right-square-fill

Your code should be
driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("i.bi.bi-arrow-right-square-fill")).Click();


I would suggest you take some time to read some articles on CSS selectors (and maybe XPath as well) to familiarize yourself with the syntax.
Here are some references...
W3C Spec
Selenium Tips: CSS Selectors by SauceLabs

hello, thank you for the answer but the code did not work

Well there's nothing we can do until you update your question with more info.
